# PDO Construct error - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a wine shop in PHP that accesses a MySQL database and pulls the wines data onto a webpage. However, after getting it all working nicely I have now come across a PDO Construct error and do not know why.

The error is as follows:

> Warning: PDO::__construct() [pdo.--construct]: [2002] A connection
>   attempt failed because the connected party did not (trying to connect
>   via ***HOSTNAME***) in C:\webdev\shop\selectfromwines.php on line 5

It seems to relate to the following piece of code:

```
$database = new PDO('mysql:host=HOSTNAME; dbname=co525', 'co525', 'co525');
```

Any ideas where I might be going wrong?

P

Comment: add try catch to see if u have error, like <?php
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
    foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * from FOO') as $row) {
        print_r($row);
    }
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}

Comment: Is `HOSTNAME` the value that is in code? I.e., do you have a string `HOSTNAME` or some real hostname (like `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`) there?

Comment: I have the actual host name there. I just tried try catch and it gave me the same error.

Comment: Does MySQL server use default port? If not, it should be specified in DSN.

Comment: Yeah it uses default port 8888.

Comment: IIRC the default MySQL port is 3306, not 8888. Make sure you are connecting to the correct port

Comment: Yeah it still doesn't work when I connect to 3306 or when I set the default to 8888 by adding the port number onto the end of the host name

Comment: Don't "*add the port number onto the end of the hostname*". Port is specified by adding `"port=<port>"` to DSN, i.e., your DSN should be `"mysql:host=HOSTNAME;port=8888;dbname=co525"`.

Comment: doesn't work. i think i'm doing something very basic wrong. It was working when I did it at my friends house, and then I brought it home and it stopped working :/

Comment: Is the DB server accessible from your computer? If it was on friend's computer or in his local network, that could be the problem. It's hard to tell without knowing *hostname* and with buggy PDO's error message... Maybe try `var_dump(mysql_connect('hostname:8888', 'co525', 'co525'))` and see if there it produces any meaningful error message?

Comment: var_dump gave this error: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\webdev\shop\selectfromwines.php on line 5

Comment: and yes its accessible from my computer i've accessed it before and it worked

Comment: Well, when using `mysql_connect()`, it's cleary stated that **No such host is known**.

Answer (score 0):

is HOSTNAME real host name? If not - use correct address. If you have local db, try 127.0.0.1 or localhost

Comment: No, sorry hostname is the real host name I just changed it for the purposes of this message.

Comment: Can you try dsn without space. Like this: `mysql:host=HOSTNAME;dbname=co525`

Answer (score 0):

Open your php.ini and set the following:

```
pdo_mysql.default_socket=”/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock”
```

Comment: @user832488 its default in server. create a new php.ini and use above code and save it in server

Comment: To find php.ini that is used by PHP, use `var_dump(php_ini_loaded_file());`.

Comment: @user832488 use these steps http://hostmonsterforum.com/showthread.php?5687-Can-t-find-PHP.ini to locate your php.ini

Comment: @jeni, why do you think that he uses cPanel? And what's wrong with using `php_ini_loaded_file()` for getting filename of used php.ini file? Anyway, from comments below the answer, it seems that he has problems with hostname.

Comment: @binaryLV i thought he is struggling to use `php_ini_loaded_file()` thats why i suggested the steps. anyway it il be good if he got solved